# Chains and homotopy type

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $$C^{\ast}:\mathbf{sSet}\rightarrow E_{\infty}\text-\mathbf{dgAlg}$$
be the cochain contravariant functor from the category of simplicial sets to the category of $E_{\infty}$-dg-algebras (over $\mathbb{Z}$).

> **Theorem (Mandell)**: Suppose that $X$ is of finite type and $Y$ is nilpotent space of finite type. Then  $C^{\ast}:[X,Y]\rightarrow [C^{\ast}(Y),C^{\ast}(X)]$ is
>   split injective. Moreover, there exists a natural map $\epsilon: [C^{\ast}(Y),C^{\ast}(X)]\rightarrow [X,Y]$ such that: $\epsilon\circ C^{\ast}=id$ and if $  f,g \in [C^{\ast}(Y),C^{\ast}(X)]$ with $\epsilon(f)=\epsilon(g)$ then $H^{\ast}(f)=H^{\ast}(g)$.

Here $[X,Y]$ is the set of homomorphisms in the homotopy category of simplicial sets and $[C^{\ast}(Y),C^{\ast}(X)]$ is the set of homomorphisms in the homotopy category of $E_{\infty}$-algebras (over $\mathbb{Z}$).

**question:** Is the Mandell theorem still valid if $Y=K(G,1)$ where $K(G,1)$ is the Eilenberg-MacLane space and $G$ is a finite group.

Comment: You might hope to relax the finite type restriction a little bit, but not all the way down to just connectedness. Whenever $X$ is an acyclic space, then $C_{\ast}(X) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$ and the injectivity will fail for $X = Y$.

Comment: @PiotrPstrągowski you are right, I will put some restrictions...

Comment: For any question of this general type, the first thing to do is to ask what counterexamples you can get from the Kan-Thurston theorem.